# Get method for int Array

Tags: java

I have an array of `int [] scores = new int[SCORES];` where `SCORES = 5` and I want to create a method that will return my array of my `int`. Is it possible with a get method? With a `String`, `getScore` works fine but what about an `int [] getScore`?

```
public String  getScore() {
    String i = "";

    for (int scoresIndex =0; scoresIndex< scores.length; scoresIndex++)
        i += scores[scoresIndex]+"   ";

    return i;
}


public int [] getScores() {
    ////_____////
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `public int[] getScores() { return scores; }` work?

Comment: are you asking iif it is possible to have an int [] as a return type?

Comment: Why you ask when it is much simpler to try it? Plus this thing is is ultimately basic - you should study the basics before you start to ask.

Comment: @PhilippReichart: That *does* work, but it's dangerous. It would allow the caller to modify the internal state of your object.

Answer (score 3):

You could just return the array:

```
public int[] getScores() { return scores; }
```

You can also choose to give them a copy instead:

```
public int[] getScores() { return scores.clone(); }
```

The latter approach is safer because it prevents your caller from corrupting your object's internal state, but of course it comes with a small performance penalty because of the extra copying.

Comment: Good point with the `clone()` -- I usually rely on FindBugs to tell me this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] getScores(){ return scores ;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be fine for what you want.

```
public int[] getScores()
{
    // any other code
    return scores;
}
```